# Index-Match to Return Adjacent Cell of Closest Matched Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

This is a simplified version of my 2 tables:

[image]

I need to be able to fill in the missing values in **Table2** based on the closest match of the adjacent measurement value to those values in **Table1** for that measurement & type.

For example, in row 18, I need to look up the closest match of cell **B18** [4.3] to cells **B3** and **B11** (since those two are the only type A records), and return the adjacent *measurement2* of the closest match into cell **C18**.  Or, in row 19, I need to look up the closest match of cell **C19** [2.3] in cells **C6:C8** and return the adjacent *measurement1* into cell **B19**.

Comment: But in this case, 5.5 and 3.1 of A are both 1.2 away from 4.3. What gives?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, didn't catch that.  I guess I'd have to either return higher or lower match in those instances, and keep it consistent throughout the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I don't know if it can be further simplified (there are some calculations made twice in the formula), but I came up with this for cell C18:

```
=INDEX(C$3:C$12,MATCH(9^99,IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))),C$3:C$12)))
```

And this for cell B19:

```
=INDEX(B$3:B$12,MATCH(9^99,IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),B$3:B$12)))
```

---

**EDIT2:** As barryhoudini pointed out, there was a mistake in there which his formula corrected. I edited the above two formulas. Otherwise, as he correctly mentioned, you can use this formula for C18 as well:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18‌​,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))),C$3:C$12))
```

---

Notes:

1. Those are array formulas and will work only with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of only <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. The formula will get the last match in the table, in this case for A with measurement1 of 4.3, it will return 2.8, in cases where there's the same difference.

**EDIT1:** Okay, for consistency, I came up with this one to always get the higher match in B19:

**EDIT3:** And used `LOOKUP` instead of `INDEX`/`MATCH` for a little shorter formula and also fixed the first column issue.

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MAX(IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12))=IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12),IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),B$3:B$12)))
```

And this one for C18:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MAX(IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12))=IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12),IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),C$3:C$12)))
```

For the lower match, B19:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MIN(IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12))=IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12),IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A19,ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),B$3:B$12)))
```

And for C18:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MIN(IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12))=IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12),IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),C$3:C$12)))
```

---

**EDIT4:**
For two types:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MAX(IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12))=IF(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19))=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12),IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),B$3:B$12)))
```

And this one for C18:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MAX(IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12))=IF(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12),IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),C$3:C$12)))
```

For the lower match, B19:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MIN(IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12))=IF(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19))=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),C$3:C$12),IF(ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A19)*($D$3:$D$12=$D19),ABS($C$3:$C$12-$C19),999)),B$3:B$12)))
```

And for C18:

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(MIN(IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12))=IF(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),B$3:B$12),IF(ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18)=MIN(IF(($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18),ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18),999)),C$3:C$12)))
```

Comment: Works great Jerry! Just to stay consistent with my original post for future viewers,  where your equation lists $C16 and $B15, I would use $C19 and $B18 for my tables. Clearly just a remnant of how you had it set up in your table, but just thought I'd add that.  Thanks!

Comment: @John Oh, woops, you're right, I had put table2 immediately after table1 ^^;. I'll change that immediately.

Comment: @tigeravatar at some point, I didn't know how to generate only the higher or lower, so I just copy pasted the generated list some more time ^^; There is surely a shorter way, oh well.

Comment: You'll get wrong answers if there are duplicate values in the table, e.g. if you change B12 in the table to 3.1 your first C18 formula returns 3.4 from C12 although A12 is "B". You need to duplicate the condition from the MIN(IF part within the lookup value of MATCH to stop that:  `=INDEX(C$3:C$12,MATCH(9^99,IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))),C$3:C$12)))`......or you can shorten that with LOOKUP instead of INDEX/MATCH, i.e. `=LOOKUP(9^99,IF(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=$A18,ABS($B$3:$B$12-$B18))),C$3:C$12))`

Comment: @barryhoudini interesting, except both of your formulas throw "the formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: @barryhoudini Thanks, I didn't catch that error. I'll correct it tomorrow morning, I'm about to crash right now xD

Comment: @John This is the site's doing. After getting the error, excel should highlight the part causing error. Just backspace a few times and rewrite the same thing.

Comment: Great Jerry, erasing and retyping worked.  Thanks @barryhoudini

Comment: Sorry to reopen this thread, but I still need some clarification on this syntax.  How would I adapt this equation to include yet another match - call it Type 2 in column D - that had possible values of Q-T. For example, I might need to return the closest match same general idea as above, but for a measurement that is both type 1 "A" and type 2 "T".

Comment: @John It's okay, don't worry :) I amended the formulae. Basically, `$A$3:$A$12=$A18` has to become `($A$3:$A$12=$A18)*($D$3:$D$12=$D18)` (Assuming the type 2 in table2 is in column D as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would set up table 2 a bit differently, like so:

[image: Index Match Closest Value]

The **array** formula in cell D18 and copied down is:

```
=INDEX(IF(B18=$B$2,$C$3:$C$12,$B$3:$B$12),MATCH(MIN(IF($A$3:$A$12=A18,ABS(IF(B18=$B$2,$B$3:$B$12,$C$3:$C$12)-C18))),IF($A$3:$A$12=A18,ABS(IF(B18=$B$2,$B$3:$B$12,$C$3:$C$12)-C18)),0))
```

In order to confirm an array formula you will need to use **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of just Enter.

Comment: This also works great tigeravatar.  And is definitely a more efficient way of going about it.  But in the interest of not having to reorganize my data, I'm going with Jerry's suggestion.  Thanks!